# Distributed nature of Memcached

Tags: memcached, distributed-computing

I am studying distributed computing these days, and was curious to see how Memcached works. The Wiki says :

> memcached is a general-purpose distributed memory caching system

A look at the [architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached#Architecture) explains memory caching, but I fail to understand the way "distributed computing" works here. The servers are not even aware of each other - what about fault tolerance !

Can someone please help me get a "flow" of how data flows in such system ? And how does the client understand which server holds the required data (in case of a cache miss)

Thanks !

Comment: http://www.mikeperham.com/2009/01/14/consistent-hashing-in-memcache-client/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to figure out the very same thing. As best as I can figure, distributed in this sense does not imply replication as one would expect with modern, distributed, cloud-like applications. In the sense that memcached is distributed, it seems to simply mean it is not necessarily local.

[A similar question was asked](https://serverfault.com/questions/210417/how-is-memcache-distributed), specifically detailing a use case with PHP, with [an answer](https://serverfault.com/a/210437) that addresses the memcached claim of being distributed.

Answer (score 0):

A group of friends and I (with some beers on the table) were arguing whether memcache was actually a distributed system.

I was on the group that claims the word "distributed" needs to be removed from Memcache definition, 'cause memcache doesn't know anything about other nodes. The distribution is handled entirely by the clients.